# Backup Subversion Repositories with rsync

Tags: apache-2.2, backup, svn, rsync

Is it ok to Synchronize the SVN Repository directory using the `rsync` command. Will there be any issues, will the repository files get corrupted due to this? (I use rsync only when no one is using the repositories).

Comment: By "synchronize," you do mean one-way-only, right? Have you looked at svnsync?

Comment: @TheCleaner it's not a duplicate since the question is about `rsync` tool.

Comment: I disagree, the other question and the question it is linked to include pros/cons of using `rsync`.  And why would you include the "proper" ways of doing it instead of simply your first sentence if it were only about `rsync`?  But that's the beauty of voting.  You can vote to keep it open under Review as can others.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to use `rsync` for backup tasks (*don't forget to run [`svnadmin freeze`](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svnadmin-freeze) before starting `rsync`!*). However, Subversion already includes complete range of backup tools:

- [`svnadmin dump / load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin),
- [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup) for live backup (without interrupting clients operations),
- [remote repository replication with `svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication),
- [remote repository backup and restore with `svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump).